# What is the correct way to assign an exception to a variable in a Python notebook?

Tags: python, exception, jupyter-notebook, syntax-error

I am working with a notebook that uses the following syntax to set variables to later raise exceptions in the code:

`data_format = raise NotImplementedError("Select a data format for your kaggle entry! See docstring of 'assemble_predictors_predictands' for description of data_format.")`

But VS Code raises this error when running the notebook:

```
data_format = raise NotImplementedError("Select a data format for your kaggle entry! See docstring of 'assemble_predictors_predictands' for description of data_format.")
              ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
```

What is the correct way to set a variable equal to an exception?

Comment: Exceptions are just objects like any other. `a = b` works the same regardless of what `b` evaluates to.

Comment: As a side note, it looks like you're trying to use `NotImplementedError` in an unconventional way. Other people using your code may be confused if you re-use builtin exceptions to do different things.

Comment: Thanks, @Brian61354270 Yes I agree this is unconventional. Not my code, just trying to get it to work without changing much. Not sure why this throws an invalid Syntax error though, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"raise" is a statement. Trying to assign a "raise" statement to a variable and later just mention that variable is an indicator you should learn some more of Python syntax, imperative programing and functions

If you want to try going ahead without stepping back and checking these concepts anyway you can write it as a function instead

```
def data_format():
   raise NotImplementedError(...)
```

And call it like a function.

Just for keeping the answer complete: you can also assign an Exception instance to a variable - but you need to use the "raise" statement at the point you want the exception to take place, not just mention, or try to use it:

```
data_format = NotImplementedError(...)
...
raise data_format
```

You really shouldn't do this, though, because if you end up raising the same exception object twice, you'll get messed-up tracebacks. Constructing an exception when you raise it is less error-prone.

Comment: Thanks, yes I agree this not the best syntax. It is not my code, just trying to get it to run. Do you know why VS Code would think it is invalid syntax though?

Comment: @p1unge: Because it's just completely invalid. It has never been valid, in any Python version. If you found code that tried to assign a `raise` statement to a variable, then you found broken garbage code.

Comment: Okay great, that is what I was expecting. I really did not understand what the original author was trying to do here.